# Can Inner Lightning components have design attributes exposed for admins to configure?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-community

Lets assume you have a container lightning component that contains an inner lightning component called .

Is There a way to expose design attributes of "innerComp" directly on Lightning experience Edit Page / Lightning Builder. without having to pass them on from the outer most component.

It seems redundant if you have a hierarchy of components and you have to pass attributes that are needed in the inner most component all the way from the outermost component.

Comment: I don't think it's possible because we map the component attributes to the design component.

Comment: No can do. even with component inheritance it is not possible